# Kaltura: Cuepoints not triggered instantly

Tags: javascript, kaltura

I am using kaltura dynamic embed player in my application, there user can set cue points to video. When i set any cue point on video,it is not reflected on player instantly. Sometimes, it takes 2 or 3 min to reflect. We are giving a preview functionality, so that's why i need it instantly.

**Add cuepoints on kaltura**

```
var cuePoint = new kaltura.kc.objects.KalturaAdCuePoint();
        cuePoint.entryId = entryId;
        cuePoint.startTime = startTime;
        cuePoint.title = title;
kalturaClient.cuePoint.add(function(results) {
                callback(results);
            });
```

**Events to listen cue points**

```
kWidget.embed({
        'targetId': 'embedPlayer',
        'wid': '',
        'uiconf_id' : '',
        'entry_id' : entry_id,
        'flashvars':{  
            'autoPlay': false,
        },
        height:height,
        width:width,
        'readyCallback': function( playerId ){
            console.log( "kWidget player ready: " + playerId );
            player = $( '#' + playerId ).get(0);
            player.kBind( "adOpportunity", "cuePointReached");
        }
    })

var cuePointReached = function(qPoint){
    console.log("cuePointReached " + qPoint)
}
```

I just want to know, is it a behaviour of kaltura or i am doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override cue point data at run time.

```
<script>
    kWidget.embed({
        'targetId': 'kaltura_player',
        'wid': '_243342',
        'uiconf_id' : '13306622',
        'entry_id' : '0_uka1msg4',
        'flashvars': {
            'vast': {
                'trackCuePoints': true
            },
            'mediaProxy':{
                'entry':{
                    'name':"This shows partial runtime override of entry name"
                },
                'entryCuePoints': [{
                    "protocolType": 1,
                    "adType": 1, 
                    "cuePointType": "adCuePoint.Ad",
                    "startTime": 5000,
                    "sourceUrl": "http://projects.kaltura.com/mdale/hotelVastAd.xml"
                }]
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```